# Angular 5 BehaviorSubject data not update UI

Tags: angular5, rxjs5

I use  to change dynamic child component in body and keep static header, bottom and menu. 
My problem: When use BehaviorSubject as shared-data between components, then UI (*ngFor) not be updated event shared-data transferred well. I am using Angular 5.2.0, RxJs 5.5.6

My app has flow:
user click search button on Layout-top.component.ts -> fetch data from Backend server by Home.service.ts-> set data in BehaviorSubject object.

On Home.component.ts constructor always subscribe shared-data from Home.service.ts -> change data of Home.component.ts -> display them.
1. App.compoenet.ts

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'xxx',
  template:
    `
    <gotop position="200"></gotop>  
    <layout-top></layout-top>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <layout-bottom></layout-bottom>
    `
})

export class AppbComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.spinner.hide();           
    }

    message:string;

    constructor(private spinner:Spinner){

    }
    public ngOnInit(){
        this.spinner.show();
    }

}
```

2. Layout-top.component.ts

   public doSearch(){
       let filter = {
           xx:'XXX'
       };
       this.homeService.setData(filter);
    }

3.Home.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeService extends BaseService{
    public data =new BehaviorSubject<DataType>(<DataType>{});
    public eventFilter: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter();
    public constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
            private _const: Const,
            private util:Util,
            private appref: ApplicationRef) {
       super(_const, util);
    }

    public listProduct(filter):Observable<any>{
        const url = url to my backend api
        let headers:HttpHeaders = this.util.header(this._const, null, 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(
            url,
            filter,
            {headers})
            .map(res => {
                return res;
            });
    }

    public getData():Observable<DataType>{
        return this.data.asObservable();   
    }

    public setData(filter:any):void {
        const listProduct$ = this.listProduct(filter);
        listProduct$.subscribe(res => {
            this.data.next({res:res, filter:filter});
        });
    }
    public cleanData() {
        this.data.next(null);
    }
}
```

4. layout-top.html

5.home.html

```
  <div class="product-item"
            *ngFor="let item of listProducts">
     <!--display some thing here-->
</div>
```

6.home.component.ts

```
 constructor(private service: HomeService,               
                private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef,
                private zone:NgZone,private appref: ApplicationRef ){

        this.subsListProduct = this.service.getData().subscribe(obj=>{
            this.zone.run(()=>{
                $("#in-blur").css("display", "block");
                if(!obj){
                    return;
                }
                const res = obj.res;
                const filter = obj.filter;
                if(res && filter){
                    this.listProducts = res.list;
                    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
                }
            });

            setTimeout(()=>{
                $("#in-blur").css("display", "none");
            }, 1000);//for test loading spinner. will be remove in product            
        });
    }
```

"this.listProducts = res.list;" work fine, ther listProducts be updated, but UI is not any change.

Many people advised use zone.run() or ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() but not work in my app. Plz support me.

Comment: anyone help me? I stuck with matter over 1 day.

Comment: I think problem in  <router-outlet></router-outlet>. I tested with transfer data from layout-top component to layout-bottom component, all work fine - this is sibling component(work as Angular document). But with router-outlet, seem Angualr treats difference, then ChangeDetectorRef cannot detect data change (?!)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to map observable data to views is to use the async pipe - https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe - this way all the change management and unsubscribing form the observable is handled for you. So in your example:

The view:

```
<div class="product-item"
        *ngFor="let item of (listProducts | async)?.list">
     <!--display some thing here-->
</div>
```

The ? before .list makes the property optional, so nothing will break if list is is null or undefined

The home component:

```
constructor(private service: HomeService,               
        private appref: ApplicationRef ){

    this.listProducts = this.service.getData();

}
```

If you need to manipulate any of the data from the observable before displaying in the view do that in a .map, eg.

```
constructor(private service: HomeService,               
        private appref: ApplicationRef ){

    this.subsListProduct = this.service.getData()
    .map(obj => {
         if (obj.list && obj.filter) {
             return obj;
         } else  {
             return null;
         }
     });
}
```

You should also consider dropping jquery for doing your css changes and use ngClass in your view to do this instead - https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Thank you glendaviesnz! I will try with AysncPipe, but this has most disadvantage: difficult (or impossible) execute complexity process of Observable in template. I know use jQuery for update css is crazy/not compatible, I prefer to jQuery for caculate and re-declare some properties: detect scroll top/bottom, resize height/width of some thing.